# Problem in catalog rules

Tags: catalog, catalog-price-rules, price-rules, ce-1.9.2.3

When I apply a catalog price rule, appears this error:
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Condition/Abstract.php on line 301

How can I solve?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is occurring because your `maximum execution time` is exceeded, So here is the solution you can try,

Increase your `Maximum Execution time`, So here you have the ways to change it.
`in value of max exe time 300sec is equal to 5min` Just use one of method mention below. To verify your changes done, Create a php file named `info.php` and copy below code, Upload file to your server, So you can check current time as well.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

There you can find max_execution_time value.

1. In `.htaccess` write`php_value max_execution_time 300`
2. In `index.php` write `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);`
3. In `php.ini` write or change `max_execution_time = 300`

Note: You can increase more time from `300 to 18000` just to confirm if its time related `error`, If your `problem` still persists then there will be other `bug`.

Comment: Are there any risks associated with this change?

Comment: no there is no risk to do these changes, Also i add few things in post which may help you more.